# Install DRC Sim on Ubuntu 12.04 + Groovy

Tags: gazebo, drcsim, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

I have installed ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to install DRCSim without installing fuerte. Is there a way of do this? If so, Where can I find some instructions for doing it?

Thanks,

Gustavo.

**EDIT**

Error message after installation, changing 'fuerte' for 'groovy' and cloning repos:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [17411]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 895d6d12-c6d0-11e2-bc6b-001e65d8adfa
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [17424]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [17438]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

process[atlas_robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [17444]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/usr/local/share/drcsim-2.6/worlds/atlas.world].
Warning [Converter.cc:58]   Version[1.2] to Version[1.4]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
process[multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [17466]
Dbg [pelvis] has no parent joint
process[tf2_buffer_server-5]: started with pid [17486]
[ WARN] [1369660975.712611124]: You've passed in true for auto_start for the C++ action server at [/tf2_buffer_server]. You should always pass in false to avoid race conditions.
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.39.39.155
process[multisense_sl/camera/stereo_proc-6]: started with pid [17528]

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.39.39.155
[ WARN] [1369660981.154465495]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1369660981.154710010]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1369660981.154753522]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1369660981.155109363]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:62] escalating to SIGKILL on client
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/gustavo/.ros/log/895d6d12-c6d0-11e2-bc6b-001e65d8adfa/gazebo-2*.log
```

Glxgears runs fine and gazebo works on its own. What can be causing gazebo to stop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2984/install-drc-sim-on-ubuntu-12.04-+-groovy/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 20 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-05-28**:
What kind of GPU do you have?  There have been [reports](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/283) that the GPU-based laser sensor on the Atlas robot causes this kind of crash on Intel GPUs.  There's a [fix](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/317/files-for-cpu-lidar) on the `drcsim_2.6` branch that provides launch files that use the old CPU-based laser sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We haven't been testing drcsim + ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04, and we don't make binary installation packages for that configuration, but building from source should work.

Start by following the [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install#Ubuntu_Linux_2) for compiling from source on Ubuntu, replacing each occurrence of `fuerte` with `groovy` as you go.

If you encounter problems, please report them.  And if/when you are successful, please update the [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install#Ubuntu_Linux_2) for future users who want to do the same thing; e.g., with a note to say that replacing `fuerte` with `groovy` is sufficient, or if necessary, with a separate section that details the groovy-specific process.

**Update, responding to error output**: Most of that console output is normal, but gazebo is definitely dying:

```
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:62] escalating to SIGKILL on client
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
```

My first guess is that there's a problem with your GPU drivers.  What kind of GPU do you have?  Do tools like `glxgears` work properly?

Try launching gazebo on its own, without the drcsim launch file (assuming here that you installed to `/usr`):

```
. /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh
gazebo
```

Can you insert models into the world, manipulate the user camera, etc.?

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-25**:
Thanks... I will try it...

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-27**:
Hi, on installation all goes fine changing 'fuerte' for  'groovy'. But trying to start DRCsim, gazebo crashes. On answer I paste the error message.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-27**:
glxgears and gazebo works on its own... Let me try to insert models...

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-05-28**:
I've seen problems with graphic cards supporting DRI (hence glxgears is running, even gazebo starts) but are not powerful enough to run big models or some kind of sensors. Are you using an intel card? Nvidia? ATI?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-29**:
Now it works!.. Something I forgot was to checkout each repo to newest version branch. After doing this and rebuild, finally I can roslaunch atlas.launch.